# How to get wallet private key by password using Ethers npm module

Tags: wallets, nodejs, polygon, password

I am using 'ethers' for wallet. And I want private key for login to wallet by password. How can I get that.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the problem? You can't derive the private key of a user by using an npm package.

Comment: I am creating an EVM based wallet and for user login to wallet we need user private key

Answer (score 0):

If by "password" you mean "mnemonic", then https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet.fromMnemonic. If you mean like, the users metamask password, it's not possible.